# New Samsung monitor looks blurry connected to my PC

Tags: windows-8, display, resolution, hdmi

I just setup a new Samsung LED Monitor. The T24C550 model.

I installed the driver that came with it (which is the latest).
I updated my video card drivers to the latest edition.
I'm connected via HDMI.

And it looks like crap.

It's somewhat blurry and the colors are faded/washed out. Text is very blurry. The resolution (1920x1080) extends beyond the monitor.

What am I doing wrong? I've attached an image to maybe give you an idea of how poor this looks. You can't see the desktop being cut off in this screen capture, but it is getting cut off at the edges. Rightn ow I only see about the top 60% of the taskbar.
[image: t]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an AMD GPU, go into Catalyst Control Center, and check the "Scaling options" settings.
It only happens with HDMI.

[image]

Comment: Have an NVIDA GTX 680

Comment: I was able to use the Nvidia Control Panel to adjust the resolution over scaling. Now I just need to get the font and colors to not look like crap.

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to get the screen to look right by adjusting the brightness/color and lowering the sharpness level.

Comment: @JackMarchetti: That's a weird solution. You should try using DVI, instead of HDMI then. I mean, adjusting settings like that should not be needed at any times. With TVs there are times when you have to mess with refresh rate or resolution, but that's not your case for sure. Sorry I couldn't help more. Had an Nvidia card and used it with HDMI but I never had such problems, only with AMD.

Comment: Monitor only has VGA and two HDMIs. It looks great now, just had to get the settings correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one but I just had the same problem with the same TV.

Plugging the TV into HDMI 2 immediately solved all the problems.

I've read somewhere before that if you call the HDMI channel "PC" or something, TV's are smart enough to know to do something different than a standard STB with overscan settings (and I noticed they changed too) and other settings.